# in Maven how to create a zip file with all dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, testing

For doing testing on AWS farm it is asking me to upload the maven zip file with dependencies?

How do I create a zip file of the project with all dependencies  using
maven?

Comment: a zip file? why would you want a zip file?

Comment: You can create a zip file [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/index.html) but I would also ask why you want to have ZIP file for AWS ?

Answer (score -1):

Rather, the question is : why do you need a zip for AWS ?

For your original question, you can use Apache Maven Assembly Plugin to create a zip file.